# Integration with trigonometric substitution using x=a.cos instead of x=a.sin

Tags: integration, substitution

I was trying to integrate $ \int \frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x^2} dx $.

If I substitute $ x=3\sin{\theta} $ the result will be $ -\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}-\sin^{-1}{(\frac{x}{3})} +C$, which is the correct result.

**My question is:** why can't I substitute **$ x=3\cos\theta $** instead of **$ x=3\sin\theta $**? The square root will be canceled the same way.

The result is $ -\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}+\cos^{-1}{(\frac{x}{3})} +C$, which doesn't match.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider labeling the constants as $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then check out egreg's hint below.

Comment: So my result is correct?

Comment: Yeah,  $\cos^{-1} (\frac x3) =  -  \sin^{-1} (\frac x3) + \frac \pi 2$. They only differ by a constant, which is "absorbed into" $C$.

Comment: Thanks man, really helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for any $x\in[-1,1]$,
$$
\arcsin x+\arccos x=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$